# Taking three steps with limited space

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, shiurim-measurements

The Shulchan Arukh describes the measurement of the three steps back taken after *amidah* in OC [122:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.123.3?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) (translation my own):

> וְשִׁעוּר פְּסִיעוֹת אֵלּוּ, לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת, הוּא כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּתֵּן
>   גּוּדָל בְּצַד עָקֵב
>
> And the size for each of these steps is at least enough so that the
>   big toe is placed alongside the heel.

I have noticed that in the vast majority of *shuls* there is not sufficient space in the pews to take three steps back with the measurements described. What should one do if he finds himself in such a pew? I can think of three possible options but do not have sources to support option 2 or 3.

1. Step out to a space where there is sufficient room
2. Take steps directly back with smaller measurements
3. Take steps on a diagonal so that the measurements are correct

Comment: What about step back and up onto the chair/pew?

Comment: Lichora Svara pshuta: not walking through walls and people. I often seen people that push others in way to make beautyful 3 steps. I do not say what I think about this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I heard that Rav Chaim Kanievsky holds that one should take the steps sideways or on a diagonal. I personally saw the Chazan in his shul take three steps back on a diagonal that was nearly sideways.